# How to get all specific fields from one ACF Group?

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have created few question/ answers using ACF.

Field names are question_1, question_2 and so on.

My codes are:

```
<?php if (get_field('question_1') == 'yes') && (get_field('question_2') == 'yes'):?>
Answer: Yes
<?php:?>
Answer: No
<?php endif; ?>
```

How to limit code repetition, if I have 100 questions in number, I just want to avoid using

`get_field('question_1') == 'yes' to get_field('question_100') == 'yes'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use `get_fields()` which return all fields from current page.
Additionally you can filter array checking which key matches.

Example:

```
$questions = get_fields();
$questions_array = array_filter($questions, function($key) {
    return strpos($key, 'question') === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

foreach( $questions_array as $question) {
 // your code here
}
```